# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a share service using following code:

```
whoIsApp.service('sharedScope',function($scope){
     this.domainName="google.com";
});

whoIsApp.controller('mainController',function($scope,sharedScope){

    $scope.$watch('domainName',function(){
        sharedScope.domainName=$scope.domainName;
    });
});
```

The problem is, when I run the application, I face with the error in the console:

```
Error: $injector:unpr  Unknown Provider
```

It seems a little strange since i have defined the `sharedScope`service.
what is wrong with code?

Update:

Here is definition of app:

```
var whoIsApp=angular.module('whoIsApp',['ngRoute','ngResource']);

whoIsApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when("/",{
        templateUrl:'Home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
});
```

Comment: looks like you are missing a comma.

Comment: where did i missed it?

Comment: Can you show where you have defined your whoIsApp

Comment: Have you included ngroute and ngresource js files in your application? Note: You should include these files above your app.js

Comment: @RahulArora i have solved my problem, thx bro

Answer (score 0):

there was error in function parameters, it should be like this:

```
whoIsApp.controller('mainController',function($scope, sharedScope){..
```